# How to "Offline" a Disk using Windows PE/Recovery Enviroment?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, diskmanagement, windows-pe

The Disk Management MMC snapin has a "Offline" function:

[image: Screenshot of Disk Managment showing the "Offline" context menu item]

Once used, a disk shows as Offline, with hover text "This disk is offline because of policy set by an administrator".

[image]
[image]

However, if the OS does not boot due to the contents of the disk this state can not be reached.

How can this be done to an offline system, using the recovery/Windows PE environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is stored in the registry under

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\`(disk\device\path)`\Device Parameters\Partmgr`

There is a `DWORD` value named "`Attributes`" with the following values:

`0` = Online

`3` = Offline

(decimal or hexadecimal are the same)

Device paths tend to contain some part of the device bus and name. The device path on my test system was `SCSI\Disk&Ven_&Prod_LITEONIT_LMT-256\4&35b1cb49&0&040000`.

[image: Screenshot of registry tree]

So the generalised steps are:

1. Boot into the recovery environment
2. [Mount the registry offline](https://serverfault.com/a/77525/2887).
3. Edit the registry key. In an offline system there is no "Current" ControlSet so change all of `ControlSet001`, `ControlSet002`, etc as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt and then enter the following commands in sequence:

```
diskpart
list disk <-This will give you a list of disk on the system
select disk 0 <-replace 0 by the disk ID  that you want to put offline
offline
```

Comment: The `dispart` command operates on a running OS and will not persist this state to an offline system.